# How to do dynamic routing from one component to another component through anchor tags??Which we usually do in javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

How to jump within the component sections on the same page on the click of anchor tags. This is usually known as jump link in normal HTML where we navigate through id's specified to each section and href of anchor tag is used to target that ID.

```
<div if:true={Results} for:each={Results} for:item="addon" key={addon.id} id={addon.id} title={addon.name}>
        <div class={addon.displayClass} id={addon.id}> //WE ARE USING ID DYNAMICALLY HERE
           <div
              class="nds-p-horizontal_x-large nds-m-bottom_medium nds-size_1-of-1 nds-medium-size_6-of-12 nds-large-size_6-of-12">
              <img src={addon.imageurl}>
           </div>
           <div
              class="nds-p-horizontal_x-large nds-size_1-of-1 nds-medium-size_6-of-12 nds-large-size_6-of-12 nds-align_absolute-center">
              <div class="" >
                 <h1 class="nds-text-heading_xx-large">{addon.name}</h1>
                 <p class="nds-m-top_medium nds-m-bottom_small">{addon.description}</p>
                 <!-- <ul class="nds-list_bullet nds-m-bottom_small">
                          <li>500 channels</li>
                          <li> Decoder Q included</li>
                       </ul>-->
                 <p class="nds-text_bold">€{addon.price}/mo.</p>
                 <div class="nds-m-top_large">
                    <a href="#"
                       class="nds-button nds-button_primary btn-mob-stretch nds-m-bottom_medium nds-m-right_small">Watch
                       Now</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nds-button nds-button_default btn-mob-stretch nds-m-bottom_medium">Explore
                       Content</a>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div> 
     
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The "#" in an HTTP(S) URL introduces the "fragment ID", something that can be interpreted by the browser as referencing a specific element in the HTML by ID or that can be used by JavaScript to implement some specific behaviour - frequently used for creating "bookmarkable locations" within an SPA or SPI.

Because IDs must be unique in a given HTML page and that the use of IDs is frequently hidden away within the body of a component, Salesforce typically "mangles" IDs to generate unique values. Because you are going across component boundaries references to these IDs don't get tracked. Indeed, an attempt to assume that certain IDs are available elsewhere on the page (outside the boundaries of the current component) would be an anti-pattern; the components are then tightly coupled and should likely actually be part of a single component anyway.

If you really need to provide this sort of thing, I recommend using the "[pubsub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_pubsub)" approach; have an originating component generate an event with a specific name and have the (loosely coupled) target component listen for and receive this event. When received the component can use a simple "scroll to" approach using the DOM element [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function against one of its own elements.